# Using \it, \bf in the tex file need to be convert as <italic> and <bold> in TeX4HT

Tags: bold, tex4ht, italic

When i am using `\it` and `\bf` in the tex file need to be configured as `<italic>` and `<bold>` in the tex4ht, I had already configured `\textbf` and `\textit` in my `cfg` file, i am getting the expected output, but i need to configure `\it` and `\bf`  also.

my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

{\it Chapter} 

{\bf Text Chapter} 

\textbf{Text Chapter} \textit{Text Chapter} Chapter TextChapter Text
\end{document}
```

my `cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xml,ext=xml}

\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</italic>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</bold>}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

I am getting the below output

```
<p class="noindent"><span class="cmti-10">Chapter</span></p>
<p class="indent"><span class="cmbx-10">Text Chapter</span></p>
<p class="indent"> <bold>Text Chapter</bold> <italic>Text Chapter</italic> Chapter TextChapter Text</p>
```

How to configure the `\it` and `\bf` to get `<italic>` and `<bold>`?

Note: when I am using `NoFonts` option in the `\Preamble{}` the `<span class="cmti-10">` is dismissed in the output

Comment: The commands `\it` and `\bf` have been deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: use `\itshape` and `\bfseries` or `\textit` and `\textbf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags for font switches are inserted when the DVI file is being post-processed by `tex4ht` command. When you use `NoFonts` option, this post-processing is disabled and you will get no formatting. The only way how to change it from `<span>` to something different is to process the generated HTML or XML files.

`make4ht` and `tex4ebooks` support simple build files, where you can process the files with various filters. You can run external commands, or use some simple Lua functions.

In this simple case, you can use just simple regular expressions to replace the classes according to your wishes.

Save the following file mybuild.mk4:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local replaces = {
  ["cmti-10"] = "italic",
  ["cmbx-10"] = "bold"
}
local function patch_span(s)
  return s:gsub('<span%s+class="([^"]+%-[0-9]+)">([^<]+)</span>', function(class, content)
    local element  = replaces[class]
    if element then
      return string.format("<%s>%s</%s>", element, content, element)
    end
  end)
end

local process = filter {patch_span}

Make:match("ml$", process)
```

and compile your file using

```
make4ht -uc configfile.cfg -e mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

you can configure which elements will be used for configured classes with the following code

```
local replaces = {
  ["cmti-10"] = "italic",
  ["cmbx-10"] = "bold"
}
```

modify it according to your needs.

This is the result from your code:

```
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" ><italic>Chapter</italic>
</p><!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >   <bold>Text Chapter</bold>
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   <bold>Text Chapter</bold> <italic>Text Chapter</italic> Chapter TextChapter Text </p>
```